# SIP Linphone CLI not working in Bullseye

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have configured linphone CLI to auto answer the SIP Calls.
However whenever a call is initiated, it rings twice and the busy tone plays and the SIP Client becomes unreachable.

Please guide to install and configure Linphone CLI in Bullseye to avoid the error which I facing currently.

When looked at the service it shows:

```
systemctl status sippaphone.service
● sippaphone.service - SIPPAphone
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sippaphone.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Mon 2022-11-14 18:26:30 IST; 59s ago
  Process: 803 ExecStart=/bin/bash sippaphone.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 808 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Nov 10 15:05:01 Testing-PA-Client-Buster systemd[1]: Starting SIPPAphone...
Nov 10 15:05:05 Testing-PA-Client-Buster bash[803]: Auto answer enabled.
Nov 10 15:05:05 Testing-PA-Client-Buster systemd[1]: Started SIPPAphone.
Nov 14 18:26:30 Testing-PA-Client-Buster systemd[1]: sippaphone.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Nov 14 18:26:30 Testing-PA-Client-Buster systemd[1]: sippaphone.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Please suggest how to go about it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How is your setup, how do you test, what is the behavior you expect? We don't even know if you killed the service by yourself

Comment: We have installed FreePBX 15 on Raspberry pi Buster and create SIP Extensions. This is our PBX Server. Then for clients, we have configured one of the SIP Extension with the help of linphone in Raspberry Buster and enabled auto answer feature for the same. Although SIP Extension gets registered with FreePBX Server, when we initiate a call from Telephone App where another SIP extension is configured and registered with the Server; it rings twice and instead of auto answer it plays busy tone.

Comment: Continuing:    After that its sippaphone service is dead. I have checked Network connectivity, linphone as well Server configurations however I am unable to find any reason for this behaviour. Other extensions are working as expected in the same network.

Comment: Can I get any pointers for the issue mentioned please

Comment: This would be more appropriate on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: WRT Buster: RpiOS Buster is a modified version of Debian Buster, and nothing here is unique to the former, hence it is a question about using Debian Linux Buster, and off-topic here.  The brand of hardware you are using (Raspberry Pi) is irrelevant.